# Python Selenium hangs on certain pages

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping, web-crawler

When I try to **scrape** following url, selenium doesn't respond for about 30seconds then emits error on the line with beautiful soup because there was no html code to parse. My selenium + chrome setup works fine with most websites but not this one: http://www.11st.co.kr/product/SellerProductDetail.tmall?method=getSellerProductDetail&prdNo=2609814501&trTypeCd=22&trCtgrNo=895019

What should I do to make it work?

Here's my selenium option:

```
def GetSelenium():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
    options.add_argument('headless')
    options.add_argument('lang=ko_KR')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36')
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver',chrome_options=options)
    return driver
```

```
@api_view()
def crawlOthers(request, crawl_url):
    crawl_url = request.data["requestUrl"]
    print("URL:" + crawl_url)
    driver = GetSelenium()
    driver.get(crawl_url)
    html = driver.page_source
    driver.quit()
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

    #parsing deleted
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the GetSelenium () function is wrong. I think we should declare the option value and put the contents into the chrome driver and return the chrome driver value.

I'll attach the code below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def GetSelenium():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
    options.add_argument('headless')
    options.add_argument('lang=ko_KR')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

    return driver

def crawlOthers():
    url = 'http://www.11st.co.kr/product/SellerProductDetail.tmall?method=getSellerProductDetail&prdNo=2609814501&trTypeCd=22&trCtgrNo=895019'
    print("URL:" + url)
    driver = GetSelenium()
    driver.get(url)
    html = driver.page_source
    driver.quit()
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    print(bsObj)

    #parsing deleted

if __name__ == '__main__':
    crawlOthers()
```

Comment: Oops I missed out last 2 lines of my `GetSelenium()`... Do you see any other problems?

Comment: It works fine on my pc. Do you not work the code I wrote?
If so, it could be the selenuim version, the chrome driver version, or something else. also timing issue.